# Create a simple Dropdown list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new in ROR. I want to create a simple dropdown list. Say select state from drop down. The selected value from list must be store in DB on click on submit button. How can I create this?

Comment: Right now the question is too vague to be answered, you need to provide some code and an actual coding problem. I would suggest reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and experiment a little.

Comment: Atleast show that you have tried , no ones going to make it for you if you yourself don't show any eagerness to achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/234-simple-form?view=asciicast) video tutorial. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation on [form options helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select).

Comment: Thanks to u also Isotope.